# Freeze the Table header in table

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have a created a table(with static headers), using css and jquery, Column widths changes according to the table data(Headers also change according to the data widths,This is perfectly working on Firefox, but it does not work well within IE and chrome,(Column alignment not working properly in chrome and IE),

Could anyone help me to short this out, I have tried lot of examples on the Internet, those are perfectly working with fixed column widths,

here is the code that I have used for this

**CSS**

```
.tablescroll
{ font: 12px normal Tahoma, Geneva, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; background-color:#fff; }

.tablescroll td, 
.tablescroll_wrapper,
.tablescroll_head,
.tablescroll_foot
{ border:1px solid #ccc; }

.tablescroll td
{ padding:3px 5px; }

.tablescroll_wrapper
{ border-left:0; }

.tablescroll_head
{ font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; background-color:#eee; border-left:0; border-top:0; margin-bottom:3px; }

.tablescroll thead td
{ border-right:0; border-bottom:0; }

.tablescroll tbody td
{ border-right:0; border-bottom:0; }

.tablescroll tbody tr.first td
{ border-top:0; }

.tablescroll_foot
{ font-weight:bold; background-color:#eee; border-left:0; border-top:0; margin-top:3px; }

.tablescroll tfoot td
{ border-right:0; border-bottom:0; }
```

**jQuery**

```
;(function($){

    var scrollbarWidth = 0;

    // http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/minute/calculate-scrollbar-width.php
    function getScrollbarWidth() 
    {
        if (scrollbarWidth) return scrollbarWidth;
        var div = $('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:-200px;left:-200px;"><div style="height:100px;"></div></div>');
        $('body').append(div); 
        var w1 = $('div', div).innerWidth(); 
        div.css('overflow-y', 'auto');
        var w2 = $('div', div).innerWidth(); 
        $(div).remove(); 
        scrollbarWidth = (w1 - w2);
        return scrollbarWidth;
    }

    $.fn.tableScroll = function(options)
    {
        if (options == 'undo')
        {
            var container = $(this).parent().parent();
            if (container.hasClass('tablescroll_wrapper')) 
            {
                container.find('.tablescroll_head thead').prependTo(this);
                container.find('.tablescroll_foot tfoot').appendTo(this);
                container.before(this);
                container.empty();
            }
            return;
        }

        var settings = $.extend({},$.fn.tableScroll.defaults,options);

        // Bail out if there's no vertical overflow
        //if ($(this).height() <= settings.height)
        //{
        //  return this;
        //}

        settings.scrollbarWidth = getScrollbarWidth();

        this.each(function()
        {
            var flush = settings.flush;

            var tb = $(this).addClass('tablescroll_body');

            // find or create the wrapper div (allows tableScroll to be re-applied)
            var wrapper;
            if (tb.parent().hasClass('tablescroll_wrapper')) {
                wrapper = tb.parent();
            }
            else {
                wrapper = $('<div class="tablescroll_wrapper"></div>').insertBefore(tb).append(tb);
            }

            // check for a predefined container
            if (!wrapper.parent('div').hasClass(settings.containerClass))
            {
                $('<div></div>').addClass(settings.containerClass).insertBefore(wrapper).append(wrapper);
            }

            var width = settings.width ? settings.width : tb.outerWidth();

            wrapper.css
            ({
                'width': width+'px',
                'height': settings.height+'px',
                'overflow': 'auto'
            });

            tb.css('width',width+'px');

            // with border difference
            var wrapper_width = wrapper.outerWidth();
            var diff = wrapper_width-width;

            // assume table will scroll
            wrapper.css({width:((width-diff)+settings.scrollbarWidth)+'px'});
            tb.css('width',(width-diff)+'px');

            if (tb.outerHeight() <= settings.height)
            {
                wrapper.css({height:'auto',width:(width-diff)+'px'});
//              wrapper.css({height:'300',width:(width-diff)+'px'});
                flush = false;
            }

            // using wrap does not put wrapper in the DOM right 
            // away making it unavailable for use during runtime
            // tb.wrap(wrapper);

            // possible speed enhancements
            var has_thead = $('thead',tb).length ? true : false ;
            var has_tfoot = $('tfoot',tb).length ? true : false ;
            var thead_tr_first = $('thead tr:first',tb);
            var tbody_tr_first = $('tbody tr:first',tb);
            var tfoot_tr_first = $('tfoot tr:first',tb);

            // remember width of last cell
            var w = 0;

            $('th, td',thead_tr_first).each(function(i)
            {
                w = $(this).width();

                $('th:eq('+i+'), td:eq('+i+')',thead_tr_first).css('width',w+'px');
                $('th:eq('+i+'), td:eq('+i+')',tbody_tr_first).css('width',w+'px');
                if (has_tfoot) $('th:eq('+i+'), td:eq('+i+')',tfoot_tr_first).css('width',w+'px');
            });

            if (has_thead) 
            {
                var tbh = $('<table class="tablescroll_head" cellspacing="0"></table>').insertBefore(wrapper).prepend($('thead',tb));
            }

            if (has_tfoot) 
            {
                var tbf = $('<table class="tablescroll_foot" cellspacing="0"></table>').insertAfter(wrapper).prepend($('tfoot',tb));
            }

            if (tbh != undefined)
            {
                tbh.css('width',width+'px');

                if (flush)
                {
                    $('tr:first th:last, tr:first td:last',tbh).css('width',(w+settings.scrollbarWidth)+'px');
                    tbh.css('width',wrapper.outerWidth() + 'px');
                }
            }

            if (tbf != undefined)
            {
                tbf.css('width',width+'px');

                if (flush)
                {
                    $('tr:first th:last, tr:first td:last',tbf).css('width',(w+settings.scrollbarWidth)+'px');
                    tbf.css('width',wrapper.outerWidth() + 'px');
                }
            }
        });

        return this;
    };

    // public
    $.fn.tableScroll.defaults =
    {
        flush: true, // makes the last thead and tbody column flush with the scrollbar
        width: null, // width of the table (head, body and foot), null defaults to the tables natural width
        height: 100, // height of the scrollable area
        containerClass: 'tablescroll' // the plugin wraps the table in a div with this css class
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Thank you,
Udeshika

Answer (score 0):

This plugin doesn't seem active anymore.

So I sense your issue is the same as this ticket? https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.tableScroll/issues/14

This plugin splits the thead/tbody/tfoot into separate tables to achieve the fixed header/footer effect.

**Try applying this change: https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.tableScroll/pull/7**

Judging from that Pull Request's description (3rd point), it makes sense, but I haven't done so myself.

If the above Pull Request didn't work, you'll have to roll out your own solution.

---

*I've used this plugin before. I was crafting my own table with sortable+resizable columns, and this plugin seemed like a decent-enough, simplistic base to start with in terms of fixed header/footer scrollable tables.*

*As far as I can tell, this plugin had only one intention: a scrollable table with fixed header/footer. If you are expecting any more features other than that, then you either need to start looking somewhere else, or start coding your own solution.*

Answer (score 0):

*To Freeze table header*

You may have to separate table element for the table head and the other table element for table body.

you only need few lines of jquery to make it work and the rest CSS and HTML

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tableBody').scroll(function(){
             $('.tableHeader table').css('margin-left', -    $('.tableBody').scrollLeft());
        });
    });
});
```

you can see the rest of the code example on this link:

[Freezing the table header in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079715/freezing-the-table-header-in-jquery/45273878#45273878)