# Freezing the table header in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have the following scripts to freeze my table. This works fine in Landscape/Portrait mode of screen but when table is loaded in landscape mode and rotated to portrait, the old `clone(fixed header {fix_thead})` resides with same width. On orientation change

```
jQuery(window).bind('orientationchange', function (e) {CheckInvTableFreeze ();}
```

I am calling the freeze header function again to adjust the freeze header width with new table header. On changing the orientation again multiple freezed header is appearing. How to have only one fixed table head based on my original table.

```
var CheckInvTableFreeze = function myfunction() {
var CiTable = $('#myTable'),
 CiThead = CiTable.find('thead'),
 fix_thead;

CiThead.find('th').each(function () {
    var el = $(this);
    el.css('width', el.width());
});
fix_thead = CiThead.clone().hide();
CiThead.after(fix_thead);
fix_thead.css(
{
    'position': 'fixed',
    'top': 0,
    'width': CiThead.width()
});
$(document).on('scrollstart', function (e) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('#myTable').offset().top) {

        fix_thead.show();
    }
    else {

        fix_thead.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: You could, on page load, get table header current location, then via js set the css to fixed to that location. I hesitate towards using `scrollTop` because then it'll be finicky. I'll throw an example together for you.

Comment: But'page load' doesn't fire on orientation change. :P

Comment: So when `.resize` is triggered fire off the function again.

Comment: Same problem again as changing orientation means resizing your screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

*HTML*

```
<div class="tableContainer">
      <header class="tableHeader">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Aapple</th>
              <th>Bboy</th>
              <th>Ccat</th>
              <th>Ddog</th>
              <th>Eeagle</th>
              <th>Ffoxrot</th>
              <th>Ggoat</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </header>
      <div class="tableBody">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
              <td>b</td>
              <td>c</td>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>e</td>
              <td>f</td>
              <td>g</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
              <td>c</td>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>e</td>
              <td>f</td>
              <td>g</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>b</td>
              <td>cccccccccccc</td>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>e</td>
              <td>f</td>
              <td>g</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>b</td>
              <td>c</td>
              <td>dddddddddddddddddddddd</td>
              <td>e</td>
              <td>f</td>
              <td>g</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>b</td>
              <td>c</td>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>eeeeeeeee</td>
              <td>f</td>
              <td>g</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>b</td>
              <td>c</td>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>e</td>
              <td>ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</td>
              <td>g</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>b</td>
              <td>c</td>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>e</td>
              <td>f</td>
              <td>ggggggggggggggggggg</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

*CSS*

```
.tableContainer table {
              width: 100%;
              border-collapse: collapse;
              font-size:16px;
              font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
            }
            .tableContainer table tr td{border-top-color:transparent!important;}
            .tableContainer table tr th,
            .tableContainer table tr td{
                min-width: 150px;
                min-height: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #464e54; 
                word-break: break-all;
            }

            .tableHeader {
                width: 50%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .tableBody {
                width: 50%;
                height: 200px;
                overflow: auto;
            }
```

*JQUERY*

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tableBody').scroll(function(){
             $('.tableHeader table').css('margin-left', -    $('.tableBody').scrollLeft());
        });
    });
});
```